# How to make separate IIS Express configurations based on URL in ASP.NET Core 3.1 application?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, configuration, iis-express

I have one project I want to publish on an IIS Server at two different addresses: `https://domain/test1/` and `https://domain/test2/`. Based on the address I am publishing at, I want to have different configuration settings for my project, for simplification let's say the configuration is an entry `email`.
So for the address `https://domain/test1/` I want to have the configuration `email: test1@test1.com` and for the `https://domain/test2/`, `email: test2@test2.com`.

I tried changing the configurations in the `launchSettings.json` file, but I cannot add an entry with the same name and if I change the entry's name, then it won't know to use IISExpress to publish it.

```
    "IIS Express": {
       "commandName": "IISExpress",
       "launchBrowser": true,
       "applicationUrl": "https://domain/test1",
       "email": "test1@test1.com",
       "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
       "commandName": "IISExpress",
       "launchBrowser": true,
       "applicationUrl": "https://domain/test2",
       "email": "test2@test2.com",
       "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       }
    },
```

How do I make separate configurations based on the current URL address in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Comment: I don't think your request is supported by current `launchSettings.json` design.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the launchSettings.json file is only used on the local development machine and it is not deployed. It is only used by Visual Studio.

So if you set the email setting in the launchSettings.json will not deploy to the production sever and will not be used.

Besides, as Lex says, there is not such feature which will match your requirement.

I suggest you could consider using appsetting.json and Environment variable to achieve your requirement.

You could create multiple appsetting.json with different environment.

[image]

After published, you could open the `applicationHost.config` specifying the site location and set different environment variable as below.

Notice: This workaround is only available for different IIS web site name the path is IIS web site name.

`applicationHost.config` Path: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\`.

```
<location path="domainA">
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="domainB">
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: I tried adding different settings files (appsettings.DomainA.json etc.), like you suggested, but unless it's one of the three environments: development, production or staging (i.e., appsettings.Production.json), it does nothing. I even tried appsettings.Production.domainA.json, but it didn't help.